Problems with shadows
What's the right way to make it smoother? Adding new edges doesn't help much. 

The triangle must be turned into quad. And removing edges actually is the way to go with smoothness

hello could you please share your object? https://blend-exchange.com/

Very likely you have somewhere where the artefact appears, a triangle or N-Gon. You need to turn geometry into quads to avoid any awkward edging shadows.
I can see at least one triangle in your sample.
It might also be that you have duplicated geometry (vertices, edges or faces overlapping). You can merge by distance to make sure you sort this problem out. One last step would be delete loose geometry.
Good luck with your issue!
